# unable to merge primary partition with free space

Tags: windows, partitioning

I want to merge my C drive with free space. But there isn't an option for this on Windows 8. Does anyone know how I would do this?

[image]

Comment: Right-click the free space volume, and choose **Delete Volume** from the context menu. The space will become unallocated, and you should be able to extend the volume.

Comment: it says  "This is an extended partition. If you delete it, it will become inaccessible". Should I delete it anyway ?

Comment: Yes, you should. Let me know if you fixed your issue so I can actually post an answer.

Comment: yeah it really helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

In order to extend a volume through the built-in disk management utility, there are some requirements. Here's what the documentation says:

> For logical drives, boot, or system volumes, you can extend the volume only into contiguous space and only if the disk can be upgraded to a dynamic disk.
>
> To extend a basic volume, it must either raw (not formatted with a file system), or it must be formatted with the NTFS file system.
>
> <sub>Source: [Extend a Basic Volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473.aspx)</sub>

In this case, what you need to do is to right-click the free space volume, and choose **Delete Volume** from the context menu. The space will become unallocated, and you should be able to extend the volume.

### Further reading

- [Extend a Basic Volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've just now gone through a similar problem except that in my case the partitions weren't contiguous, meaning that I had a Recovery Partition between (C:) and the free space.

In order to merge the primary partition with the free space I combined the following two answers

- [How to delete the Recovery Partition in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1023765/706430)
- [Merge non-contiguous partition on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1337959/706430)

So, I started by deleting the free space which then got me "unallocated space". After I removed the Recovery Partition using DiskPart. Then I was able to expand (this is what you mean with "merge") the primary partition just fine.