# Merge non-contiguous partition on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, vmware-fusion

I have a Windows 10 VM on a Mac using VMWare Fusion. I just extended the disk from 60 GB to 80GB. Now I'm trying to figure out how to add that space to my C: drive. The option to "Extend Volume..." is grayed out because there's a "Healthy (Recovery Partition)" between my C: partition and the new unallocated space.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to add this new space to the C: drive without using expensive third party software?

Comment: Buying partitioning software hasn’t been necessary for years now, with GParted and whatnot. However, using this method will take a long time and probably completely expand your virtual hard disk. IMHO, just doing away with the recovery partition is the best method.

Comment: Thanks. How do I remove the recovery partition? When I right click the only option I see is "Help".

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney - After making a backup of your virtual machine's virtual HDD, I suggest using Gparted, to delete the partition.

Comment: You can delete the partition from a command prompt using  `diskpart`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like:

1. It can't be done with Windows' built in Disk Management tool.
2. The de facto solution is "just use [GParted](https://gparted.org/)", which is free, open-source, and cross platform.

The suggestion to delete the recovery partition using the built-in [diskpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart) ([more here on how to use DiskPart to remove the recovery partition](https://superuser.com/q/1023765/706430)) command line tool worked for me, so in this case I ended up not needing to worry about non-contiguous partitions.

Comment: For the case of Parallels, indeed simply deleting the Recovery partition is a great solution, since we're taking full HDD backups anyway (snapshots/copies of the whole VM).  Obviously this would *not* be a good solution if Windows were the primary/host OS (in which case gparted is the best option it seems)!