# How can I use laptop camera again?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, camera

After [a clean Windows 10 update](https://superuser.com/a/1604827/706430) on my HP EliteBook 8460p, when I try to open the Camera I get the error (it's possible the error was there before but I've used that camera and know that once it was working)

> 0xA00F4244

[image]

and in the error there's a button which links to [this support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/camera-doesn-t-work-in-windows-10-32adb016-b29c-a928-0073-53d31da0dad5) (I followed and didn't solve the problem - when it comes to the drivers I couldn't spot it in the list).

As you can see from this picture, the camera exists and is in the lapton

[image]

Note that all Windows updates are in place.

[image]

In this Windows Update screenshot under "Ver atualizações opcionais" (portuguese for "See optional updates") there was a specific list. I selected them all, installed and restarted the machine. So they're all installed but the problem remains.

I searched in [Software and drivers for this HP EliteBook 8460p Base Model Notebook PC](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-8460p-notebook-pc/5056942/model/5056947) in Windows 10 OS but it gives

> We were unable to find drivers for your product.

If in that link I change to Windows 7 (64-bit) OS then I get a whole list of drivers.

Found [this interesting article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/how-to-install-and-update-hardware-drivers-in/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293) from where extracted that

> Normally, you might not find native Windows 10 drivers. If this is the case, use the latest Windows drivers available for your model. So if they only have Windows 7 drivers, try using those. Make sure you download the right drivers for your architecture (32 or 64 bit).

So from the drivers list available for Windows 7 I downloaded under "Driver-Keyboard, Mouse and Input Devices" the "HP Universal Camera Driver" and ran the .exe file. Then restarted the computer to see if that would be enough but it wasn't.

---

### Edit (26/11/2020, 2h48pm WET)

Started the PC in safe mode and the problem still happened in there. This means that the problem can be from default settings and basic device drivers.

Comment: What HP software do you have installed?

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean by that? I don't think I have any in it atm, at least searching for the term "HP" yields no results

Comment: HP OEM hardware by default has OEM software installed.  In the past I have experienced issues with OEM software specifically targeted to USB devices.  In my personal experience I had a problem with my camera not being detected due to that USB driver

Comment: Windows 7 device drivers are not compatible with Windows 10.  Device drivers on Windows 10 are distributed through Windows Update have you checked there?  Your screenshots don’t provide that particular screen with Windows Update

Comment: @Ramhound in the first screenshot I was in the Device Manager and couldn't find camera in the list. There were 4 particular drivers which have a warning sign in its icon but Windows didn't find a new driver for it. What i didn't test was to uninstall them as not sure which consequences that might bring

Comment: Drivers are installed through WIndows Update on Windows 10, not device manager.

Comment: @Ramhound do you care to explain better as I don't understand what you're saying? All updates are in place (as the last screenshot shows) and there's no W10 drivers in this HP's website for this model

Comment: Your screenshot is in another language, which I cannot actually read, and no translation has been provided.  However, it doesn't show which optional updates, are available.  If you have been trying to get a Camera to work by installing Windows 7 device drivers that would be one possible reason it's not working.

Comment: @Ramhound Noted. Yea, apologies on that language part. I just updated the question with that info. The optional updates are all installed too (they weren't until you referenced it) but the problem remains

Comment: Somthing to try, maybe see if safe mode works?

Comment: @EricRyan just checked and the camera still doesn't work there. This means that the problem can be from default settings and basic device drivers.